# How to focus on an area / button without looking too "forceful"?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, buttons, web

**Summary:** How to place a website visitor's focus on areas that'll help them see value on the rest of the page faster? It shouldn't feel intrusive, since repeating visitors might not need to see it again.

**Details:**
I want users landing on my page (https://divshow.bytebeacon.com) to click the "Play demo" button to get the idea of what the product does.

I want the button to pop a little, but not so much that it doesn't feel part of the page anymore. I've gotten some feedback on this already and the current state (as of Oct 01 2019) is where I've gotten, but wanted to hear from more people on other approaches taken to solve this issue.

Comment: The first thing I'd give you feedback on is that there should be some way to stop the "presentation" mode. Some users (like me in this case) just want to see what will happen but not watch the whole thing. Just add an overlaying one-line banner that says "stop presentation" with an X button.

Comment: @Big_Chair .. Added the stop button. The original intention was to keep the "shows" short (<30 sec), but there was a need from other customers to increase the show lengths. Because of that adding more controls specially "stop" made sense. We're still debating if we need pause or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips:

You could use the F pattern (Arrange the information from left to right in the upper lines and then less information on the next lines)To not make it pop too much simply use the colors of your brand. You should get one contrast color from there.

Also, I felt a little bit lost in your page, right now you have two buttons that fight too much with each other. If the 'loading show' button is the one that you want to change to 'play Demo' I would try to change the color of the 'beta' mark, my eyes went directly to that after seeing the first two buttons and didn't read anything.

GL!

Comment: Thanks Natalia. We received a lot of feedback and made some changes on the page (including yours on the 2 buttons fighting too much on the page). Would love to hear your thoughts again!